# Using a for loop to determine True or False

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have to use a for loop to write a function has that consumes a nonempty string and determines whether or not there is at least one digit in the string, producing True if so and False otherwise.

I tried this code but it is incorrect.

```
string = input()
def  has_digit(string):
   for character in string:
       if character.isdigit():
           print("True")
       else:
           print("False")
```

What is the point of doing a for loop in this case? And, to do a loop, would I call on the string or something else?
Confused beginner, thanks.

Comment: Your function should probably *return either `True` or `False`, not print something*. Note, this doesn't work correctly, it will print for every character in the string. But yes, your loop is set up fine, `for char in string:` is how it should go, like you have, but it's the body of the loop that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to go through each character and test it. Try this code:

```
def contains_digit(string):
    for character in string:
        if character.isdigit():
            return True   #String contains digit, stop here
    return False          #None of the characters were digits
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
string = input()
result = False
for char in string:
    if char.isdigit():
        result = True
return result
```

Of course you need to change return with something else if the loop is not in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, just pass a string to this function and it returns true or false based on the your condition.

```
def  has_digit(string):
    nodigit=1
    for character in string:
        if character.isdigit():
            nodigit=nodigit*0
        else:
            nodigit=nodigit*1
    if nodigit==1:
        print (False)
    else:
        print (True)
```

or if you want shorter code use this

```
 def  has_digit(string):
    for character in string:
        if character.isdigit():
            return True
            break
    return False
```

Comment: The `break` statement in the second snippet (which is a duplicate of my answer) is unnecessary. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034085/using-a-for-loop-to-determine-true-or-false/63034164#63034164).

Comment: @ObsoleteAwareProduce, Oo ya i have seen now and got it, return will break the loop right ?

Comment: Yes, when python encounters `return`, the function stops executing and returns to where it was called from. It will escape, wherever it is; therefore the loop will not continue.